# GUI Git client on Raspberry Pi for GitHub repositories

Tags: gratis, gui, git, github, raspberry-pi

I have a RPi 3b+ and need a fast **GUI** Git client (mainly for Python programming) to work with repositories on GitHub for my RPi.
I don't need many features, just that it should be able to commit and push to GitHub.
I am running Raspbian Buster. Are there any options?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What features do you need? What OS should it work on (there are multiple OS choices for the Raspi)? Must it be [tag:gratis], or how much would you spend if it came to a paid solution?

Comment: PS: [List questions are no good fit for Q&A sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154), and hence are [considered off-topic](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/192154) – so please be a bit more specific ;)